# How to compute probabilities in patient-observer example using EM algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

I am not sure how to evaluate myself but I would put myself with beginners for both statistics and machine-learning. 
 
I have started reading about maximum entropy likelihood and how you can use them to estimate the parameters that give the highest probability for density function of any given distribution. 
I came across a nice paper titled "[Maximum likelihood estimation of observer error-rates using the EM algorithm](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~jeromew/comp766/samples/Output_aggregation.pdf)". In this paper a model is presented in order to estimate the error rates of facets (sign, symptoms) even if patient's true response is not available. The paper on page 7 gives a complete solved example to explain how you can estimate the error-rates of each observer and the marginal probabilities. Then trying to compute the indicator variables for each patient. I understood that equation 2.3 and 2.4 were used to get the results of Table 2. My problem that I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how the results are computed in table 4. On which equation it was computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in Table 4 are the final probabilities of each patient belonging to each category, given the data, i.e. p(T_ij = 1 | data) for patient i and category j. They are calculated using equation 2.5, which represents the E-step of the EM algorithm.

In more detail:

On each iteration of EM, the algorithm does two things:

- M-step: Compute the maximum-likelihood estimates of the parameters (category martinals, p_j, and error rates, pi_jlk) based on the current values of the patient-category assignments (T_ij), using equations 2.3 and 2.4.
- E-step: Compute new expectations for T_ij = p(T_ij = 1 | data) based on current values of the parameters (p_j and pi_jlk), using equation 2.5

The full likelihood for the current values of all parameters can be computed using equation 2.7, and this should increase monotonically with each iteration of EM, until convergence (once the values of the parameters stop changing).

For the data given in the paper, the final estimates (once things have converged) of p_j and pi_jlk are given in Table 2, and the final estimates of T_ij are given in Table 4.

Here is a simple python implementation of the algorithm and example given in the paper. (Note that the final estimates from this implementation are slightly different from those given in the paper, presumably because of differences in precision or initialization):
https://github.com/dallascard/dawid_skene